# Calling Shell-methods by chain of files in subdirectories

Tags: shell, methods, call, chain, subdirectory

I'm trying to call methods from file to file with structure like:

`/root
    /subDir
        /subSubDir
           inSubSub.sh
       inSub.sh
   inRoot.sh`

Files contents:

*inRoot.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./subDir/inSub.sh
subMethod;
```

*inSub.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./subSubDir/inSubSub.sh
subMethod () {
    echo "I'm in sub"
}
subSubMethod;
```

*inSubSub.sh:*

```
#!/bin/bash
subSubMethod () {
    echo "I'm in subSub"
}
subSubMethod;
```

Result of running **$ ./inRoot.sh**

```
subDir/inSub.sh: line 2: subSubDir/inSubSub.sh: No such file or directory
subDir/inSub.sh: line 6: subSubMethod: command not found
I'm in sub
```

So, it works for the first call but doesn't work deeper.

btw: using **. ./** instead of **source ./** returns the same

How to do it right, if it's possible?

Comment: The current working directory doesn't change just because the script is sourceing or executing a file. To change current directory you *must* use `cd`.

Comment: Thank you all, guys! Very appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You must change your inSub.sh like that

```
cat ./subDir/inSub.sh

#!/bin/bash
var="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
source "${var%/*}"/subSubDir/inSubSub.sh
subMethod () {
  echo "I'm in sub"
}
subSubMethod;
```